# php bind_result

Tags: php, mysql

I have this sequence of code:

```
$connection = new mysqli('localhost','root','','db-name');
$query = "SELECT * from users where Id = ?"; 
$stmt = $connection->prepare($query); 
$stmt->bind_param("i",$id); 
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($this->id,$this->cols);
$stmt->fetch(); 
$stmt->close(); 
$connection->close();
```

The problem is that the "SELECT" might give a variable number of columns, which i retain in $this->cols. Is there any possibility to use bind_result with a variable number of parameters?...or any alternative to the solution.

Comment: You could bind to an array. Have a read at [http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#92505](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#92505)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are lucky enough to run PHP 5.3+, [mysqli_get_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) seems what you want.

```
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_array();
```